# Strange problem when saving to excel pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

I have some problem wirting to excel. I have 15 columns in my dataframe. I wish only to write 7 of them to excel and in the process use another name for the header.

Here is my code

```
cols = ['SN',  'Date_x','Material_x', 'Batch_x',  'Qty_x', 'Booked_x', 'State_x']
headers = ['SN', 'Date', 'Material', 'Batch',  'Qty', 'Booked', 'State']
df.style.apply(highlight_changes_ivt2, axis=None).to_excel(writer, columns =cols, header=headers, sheet_name="temp", index = False)
```

But I have the following errors

```
  File "/home/week/anaconda3/envs/SC/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/style.py", line 235, in to_excel
engine=engine,
  File "/home/week/anaconda3/envs/SC/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 735, in write
freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
  File "/home/week/anaconda3/envs/SC/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlsxwriter.py", line 214, in write_cells
for cell in cells:
  File "/home/week/anaconda3/envs/SC/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 684, in get_formatted_cells
for cell in itertools.chain(self._format_header(), self._format_body()):
 File "/home/week/anaconda3/envs/SC/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 513, in _format_header_regular
f"Writing {len(self.columns)} cols but got {len(self.header)} "
ValueError: Writing 15 cols but got 7 aliases
```

I tried to do debugging.. and setting pdb.set_trace()

```
df.style.apply(highlight_changes_ivt2, axis=None).to_excel(writer, columns =cols, header=headers, sheet_name="temp", index = False)
(Pdb) df.columns
      Index(['SN', 'Status_x', 'Material_x', 'Batch_x', 'Date_x', 'Quantity_x',
      'Booked_x', 'DiffQty_x', 'Status_y', 'Material_y', 'Batch_y',
      'Date_y', 'Quantity_y', 'Booked_y', 'DiffQty_y'],
      dtype='object')
(Pdb)
```

This code is running well at my home laptop though... just wondering what's wrong... the difference is only python using version 3.7 for this and 3.8 back at home

Thanks

Comment: Maybe do `df[cols].style.apply(...).to_excel(...)`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang... Hi i dun think i can use the above method...because in my function highlight_changes_ivt2,  there is calculation between Qty_x and Qty_y... Thanks for answers

Comment: You can rewrite your function so that it accept a reference dataframe: `def highlight_changes(col, ref_dataframe=df): ` then pass the dataframe with corresponding columns in.

Comment: Looks like you have all of the columns in the index. try adding `reset_index()` before `to_excel`

Comment: @DStanley  version 1.0.1...  I also did tried to install modin to speed up the calculation previously...but abandoned it eventually.....tot modin might have something to do with the problem.(previously it is working).... have to tried to start a new project in pycharm.. but still the same problem persist

Comment: @user1538798 sorry, I removed that comment after realizing that the api is the same for the previous version of pandas. I suspect the index is the main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me elaborate my idea in the comment by an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,-1))

# this is the reference dataframe
np.random.seed(1)
ref_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(4,4)))

# this is the function
def highlight(col, ref_df=None):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if c>r else '' 
                for c,r in zip(col, ref_df[col.name])]

# this works
df[[0,1,3]].style.apply(highlight, ref_df=ref_df).to_excel('style.xlsx', header=list('abc'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi I used your method and it works...but exactly what is in error with the old method?